# Flutter Web on Firebase hosting refused to make API Calls

Tags: django, flutter-web, dio, mixed-content

I have a **Flutter Web** application that I have deployed on **Firebase Hosting**.

I have a **Django** backend that I have deployed on an EC2 instance and is running on http.
I have CORS enabled in the backend, tried accessing endpoints via browsers and it works just fine.

But, when I try to make the same call using FlutterWeb, it fails.
And error type of blocked:mixed content appears. (See image below)

I want to call those HTTP endpoints and I don't want an SSL certificate mess because this is just a college project. How do I fix this?

I am using Dio on Flutter Web to make requests. What would be causing this problem?

**EDIT:**
I am using Firebase's spark plan, obviously since it's a college project. Do I need to upgrade to the blaze plan to enable Egress traffic? If so, how do I make sure that I won't be heavily charged? Any suggestions? **UPDATE:** I tried the blaze plan and got the same issue.

The console says

> Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://xxx.web.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but
> requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
> 'http://xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/menu'. This
> request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Any way to bypass this?**

[image: Network tab]